# How to display two random-post sections that are each under their own category

Tags: posts, categories

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>

 <div id="containerHOME">
<div id="left-div">
<!--Begin Sidebar-->
<div id="left-inside">
  <?php if (get_option('earthlytouch_featured') == 'on') get_template_part('includes/featured'); ?>
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

  <div class="home-squares">
    <div class="home-headings">
      <?php esc_html_e('Whats New?','EarthlyTouch'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php $args = array(
      'category_name' => 'whats', 
      'orderby' => 'DESC',
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
      'posts_per_page' => 3 
    );
    $qry = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($qry->have_posts()) {
      while ($qry->have_posts() ) { 
        get_template_part('content','blocks');
      }
      }?>
    <!-- end .home-squares -->
    <div class="home-squares">
      <div class="home-headings">
        <?php esc_html_e('Recipes','EarthlyTouch'); ?>
      </div>
      <?php $args = array(
      'category_name' => 'recipes', 
      'orderby' => 'DESC',
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 
      'posts_per_page' => 3 
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
      while ($query->have_posts() ) { 
        get_template_part('content','blocks');
      }
    } ?>
      <!-- end .home-squares -->
      <?php }; ?>  // if I take this out I get an error down at the bottom of the page
      <!-- movie -->
      <div class="movie"> <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tojlpK9zFPs"> <img src="images/video-front.jpg" width="530" height="299" alt="video" class="popmake-2673" /></a> </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end movie --> 
    <!-- end #left-inside --> 

    <!--Begin Sidebar-->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <!--End Sidebar-->
    <div id="sup-hold">
      <div id="supplementary" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Header Widget Area')) :
endif; ?>
      </div>
      <div id="mc-mobilecause-widget"> <a href="//www.mobilecause.com/feature/subscription-widget" id="powered-by-mobilecause">Mobile messaging powered by Mobilecause</a><script>!function(d,s){var s=d.createElement("script"),h=(document.head||d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);s.src="https://app.mobilecause.com/public/messaging_widgets/opvd3d/source";h.appendChild(s);}(document);</script> 
      </div>
      <div id="footer"> Copyright &copy;
        <?php
echo date("Y");
?>
        JustOneTree.org All Rights Reserved | <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a> | <a href="/terms">Policies and Terms of Use</a> | <a target="_blank" href="http://www.boplinger.com">webmaster: boplinger.com</a></div>
      <!-- end #footer --> 
  </div>
    <!-- end #footer -->
    <?php get_template_part('includes/scripts'); ?>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  </div> // error here
  <!-- end #sup-hold --> 
</div>
<!-- end #container -->
```

Comment: Please post the original code and copied code here so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: **Never** use `$wp_query` as your query variable, you are breaking the main query object. Also, you need to reset postdata after **every** custom instance of WP_Query. You also have syntax errors according to the syntax highlighter. Fix these faults and you should be good to go

Comment: Please correct your markup, and what is your question. Everything is a big unreadable mess

Comment: @PieterGoosen the moderator cleaned it up the code for me, I don't know why mine pastes in as a mess. Even this interface is a mystery. I am not a php programmer.  My question is. What code to I put into the content-blocks file based on his previous instructions. I'll try to paste in the original file that we were working from.

Comment: @peterGoosen I can't paste in my code without it becoming a mess.  Here it is online - thanks. http://7c8.96a.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/home-org.txt

Comment: @mrwweb I can't paste in my code without it becoming a mess.  Here it is online - thanks. http://7c8.96a.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/home-org.txt

Comment: @s_ha_dum Should I just give up asking this forum for help?  I really do appreciate your efforts but, I'm not getting any where and I need to get this working.  Thanks

Comment: I will fix this for you tonight @barb, but you really need to understand PHP well enough to patch in suggestions and corrections rather than require the rewriting of an entire template.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant code is here:

```
query_posts("cat=25&orderby=DESCd&showposts=3&$randomArticlesNum&caller_get_posts=1");
```

That is the query that is pulling the posts, and that is what you want to alter.

Your previous theme builder also did something that should never be done-- used `query_posts()`. Also, [both `showposts` and `caller_get_posts` have been replaced](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters). That is very old code or your previous programer did not keep up with changes to the core. Let's clean this up:

```
$args = array(
  'cat' => 25, 
  'orderby' => 'DESC',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, // used to be caller_get_posts
  'posts_per_page' => 3 // used to be showposts
);
$qry = new WP_Query($args);
if ($qry->have_posts()) {
  while ($qry->have_posts() ) { 
    $width = 40;
    $height = 40;
    $classtext = 'no-border';
    $titletext = get_the_title();
    $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext);
    $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"]; ?>
    <div class="random"><?php 
      $width = 40;
      if($thumb != '') { ?>
        <div class="random-image"> "><?php 
          print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>
        </div><?php 
      } 
      // something is broken here. the start of the following tag is missing
      ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(esc_attr__('Permanent Link to %s','EarthlyTouch'), the_title()) ?>"><?php 
        truncate_title(40);
        truncate_post(50); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- end .random --><?php
  }
}
```

I swapped `query_posts()` for a new `WP_Query` object, and I reordered for readability, eliminating as much PHP tag SPAM as I could at a quick once-over.

I don't know what `$randomArticlesNum` was supposed to do but looking at the argument list to `query_posts()` I don't see how it could have actually done anything.

You want to do the same thing again for your next Loop but change the `cat` argument. As is, both Loops have `cat=25` so there is no way that could have worked either.

You also have a broken tag in there. See the comments to the code.

One other trick: The code looks to be identical for both Loops but you are maintaining the same code in two places. That is a headache and is prone to error. Move most of the Loop code to another file and load it via `get_template_part()`:

```
$args = array(
  'cat' => 25, 
  'orderby' => 'DESC',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, // used to be caller_get_posts
  'posts_per_page' => 3 // used to be showposts
);
$qry = new WP_Query($args);
if ($qry->have_posts()) {
  while ($qry->have_posts() ) { 
    get_template_part('content','blocks');
  }
}
```

That will load a file called `content-blocks.php` from the theme root-- the same directory as the themes' stylesheet and `functions.php`.

---

I took a look at the edits you made and you didn't quite get it all right. Here is some code with notes:

```
// $randomArticlesNum does nothing, as noted previously. I am not even sure what it was supposed to do.    
// You can remove it
$randomArticlesNum = (int) get_option('earthlytouch_randomposts_num'); 
$args = array(
  // use one or the other, but not both, of the following and delete the one you don't use
  // Your original code use `cat` and the ID
  'cat' => 123, // 'cat' needs to be an ID-- a number-- not a word, 
  'category_name' => 'whats', // for a word, use 'category_name' and quote the value
  'orderby' => 'DESC',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, // used to be caller_get_posts
  'posts_per_page' => 3 // used to be showposts
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) {
  while ($query->have_posts() ) { 
    get_template_part('content','blocks');
  }
} // you were missing the PHP closing tag --> ?>
```

The same errors are in both Loops. Also, after the second one, you have a spurious closing bracket:

```
<!-- end .home-squares -->

      <?php }; ?>
```

Remove it:

```
<!-- end .home-squares -->
```

Also, get yourself a decent code editor-- something like Textwrangler (on a Mac and I'm guessing you are :)) or Notepad++.

---

I edited and reformatted your template:

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div id="containerHOME">
  <div id="left-div">
  <!--Begin Sidebar-->
    <div id="left-inside"><?php 
      if (get_option('earthlytouch_featured') == 'on') {
        get_template_part('includes/featured'); 
      } ?>
      <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="home-squares">
        <div class="home-headings"><?php 
          esc_html_e('Whats New?','EarthlyTouch'); ?>
        </div><?php 
        $args = array(
          'category_name' => 'whats', 
          'orderby' => 'DESC',
          'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
          'posts_per_page' => 3 
        );
        $qry = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($qry->have_posts()) {
          while ($qry->have_posts() ) { 
            get_template_part('content','blocks');
          }
        } ?>
        <!-- end .home-squares -->
        <div class="home-squares">
          <div class="home-headings">
            <?php esc_html_e('Recipes','EarthlyTouch'); ?>
          </div>
          <?php 
          $args = array(
            'category_name' => 'recipes', 
            'orderby' => 'DESC',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 
            'posts_per_page' => 3 
          );
          $query = new WP_Query($args);
          if ($query->have_posts()) {
            while ($query->have_posts() ) { 
              get_template_part('content','blocks');
            }
          } ?>
          <!-- end .home-squares -->
          <!-- movie -->
          <div class="movie"> <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tojlpK9zFPs"> <img src="images/video-front.jpg" width="530" height="299" alt="video" class="popmake-2673" /></a> </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end movie --> 
        <!-- end #left-inside --> 

        <!--Begin Sidebar--><?php 
        get_sidebar(); ?>
        <!--End Sidebar-->
        <div id="sup-hold">
          <div id="supplementary" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"><?php 
            if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Header Widget Area')) : endif; ?>
          </div>
          <div id="mc-mobilecause-widget"> <a href="//www.mobilecause.com/feature/subscription-widget" id="powered-by-mobilecause">Mobile messaging powered by Mobilecause</a><script>!function(d,s){var s=d.createElement("script"),h=(document.head||d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);s.src="https://app.mobilecause.com/public/messaging_widgets/opvd3d/source";h.appendChild(s);}(document);</script> 
          </div>
          <div id="footer"> Copyright &copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> JustOneTree.org All Rights Reserved | <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a> | <a href="/terms">Policies and Terms of Use</a> | <a target="_blank" href="http://www.boplinger.com">webmaster: boplinger.com</a></div>
          <!-- end #footer --> 
      </div>
    <!-- end #footer --> <?php 
      get_template_part('includes/scripts'); 
      wp_footer(); ?>
  </div> 
  <!-- end #sup-hold --> 
</div>
<!-- end #container -->
```

I do not get errors but it is difficult to test something like this without setting up a complete parallel environment. I notice that your template doesn't use `get_footer()`. Why not?

Comment: Yes, if you trouble come back I'll see what I do.

Comment: I gave you an almost drop- in replacement. Just tack the new code in under the old code in the question above.

Comment: I did drop in your code as best I could understand, and placed all the altered code above. Including creating a content-block.php.  but as you can see above it's lost its formatting.

Comment: I'll fix that formatting later tonight if no one beats me to it :)

Comment: Why are you using `$wp_query` as your query variable, you are breaking the main query object. Also, you are nowhere trying to reset your postdata after your custom query. Most probably why everything fails at the end

Comment: That is a good point @PieterGoosen.

Comment: @barb: I edited the answer. Did you see that?

Comment: Oh! I saw that someone cleaned it up but didn't realize it was fixed.  Does this mean I can drop it in and try it?  Also, do I upload the content-blocks to the theme folder?  Who are you amazing heros anyway/

Comment: No, look at my answer not your question.

Comment: There is no other answer but ***the bottom of this one has been edited***

Comment: I made changes to my prev. code.  Don't know what to put in the content-blocks anymore can't find your specfic code for that page. @s_ha_dum

Comment: @Barb : see the edit

Comment: @s_ha_dum  I've edited below yours **

Comment: @barb The edit you have done is bogus, meaning not helpful as solution to the problem. Please don't do that in general and use the comment function to tell such things to answerers. Thanks.

Comment: @s_ha_dum This template was purchased and adapted by some unknown predecessor. I am NOT a php programmer, so I have only been updating the html and css within the template structure. I would not know why it doesn't use "get_footer()" nor why this is better. Thanks for all your help.  I give up.